# Why multiple images selection is working on few devices not all devices?

Tags: java, android, gallery

This is the code for selecting multiple images and this is working on few devices.I was using nokia 3 and was able to select multiple images but on samsung note 5 only single image is being selected.
This on button click opens the intent to open multiple images but is not working on samsung note 5.I am sure that is above api 18 but still not working,why is that and how to make multiple selection work.

```
 Btn_Add_Bill_Images.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");

            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), result_load_image);
        }
    });
```

Comment: There is no requirement for an `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` activity to support multiple selection. `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE` is a *request*, not a *command*.

Comment: @CommonsWare So is there any alternative for multiple selection for images on all devices without using a library.

Comment: You could create your own UI from scratch. You can get a roster of available images from `MediaStore` and then display them yourself.